# star, form and other metadata via url?

Tags: github, github-api

I want to create a simple page of github bookmarks for myself.

I'd like to have a live star/fork/commits count on that page, so wondering if it's possible to get repository metadata via URL, so no need to make an API call?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that, you just need 2 things:

1. a library to make HTTP requests
2. a library to pick the xpath out of the HTTP response

For example, in Python:

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('https://github.com/<some repo>')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
stars = tree.xpath('//*[@id="js-repo-pjax-container"]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a')[1].text.strip()
forks = tree.xpath('//*[@id="js-repo-pjax-container"]/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]/a')[1].text.strip()
commits = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a/span[1]')[0].text.strip()
```

This works, but I guess I would ask: is it really easier than just calling the GitHub API? Certainly this is more brittle: if the page format gets changed, there's a good chance it will break those xpaths.